# how to create <input onchange='myFunction()' /> dynamically with function

Tags: javascript

I know that you can use document.createElement for this but I get a domexception from doing this:

```
document.createElement("<input onchange='myFunction()' />");
```

Error:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'createElement' on 'Document': The tag name provided ('<input onchange='myFunction()' />') is not a valid name.
```

Do you know how to create an element dynamically with a function?

Answer (score 1):

You should make it in 3 times :

- First creating the element
- Then adding the function
- Finally adding it to the dom

```js
const myFunction = () => {
  console.log("hello world")
}

const btn = document.createElement('button')
btn.innerText = "MyBtn"
btn.addEventListener('click', myFunction)
document.body.appendChild(btn)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I was too quick to ask for help. But this is the answer:

```
newInput3.onchange = myFunction;
```

myFunction should not be an actual string.